# AngularJS, how to get a model full path/name?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to change an input box value referring to its model.
The input box is inside an ng-repeat, that gets its elements from a function and not from a variable.

Is there a way for the application to print the model full path/name so that I can refer to it from the controller? (Note that the models are working, since a division beneath it with ng-show responds properly to the input model being filled.)

Comment: can you provide a fiddle of what you are trying? or a plunker would do.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you shouldn't use a function inside an ngRepeat. With the way the digest cycle works, your function will end up getting called multiple times. That's not very efficient. Instead, you should run the function from your controller and assign it to a scope variable that you pass to ngRepeat.

As it turns out, this makes the solution to your problem quite easy. You could for example use each item's `$index` to reference it from the controller.

If you post a fiddle or plunker, I can update this answer with something more specific. But it's hard to say more without some code.